# Convert dynamic Cassandra column family to static one

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-cli

Let's say I have a column family in Cassandra that was created using `cassandra-cli` like this:

```
create column family users with key_validation_class = UTF8Type and comparator = UTF8Type;
```

In terms of the [thrift to CQL3 migration guide from Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3) this is a *dynamic column family*.

When viewed from CQL3 client using `DESCRIBE TABLE users` it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  key text,
  column1 text,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
  AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC);
```

That is the expected behavior. What I want is to add column metadata so that the column family is viewed as *static*.

So I tried this using `cassandra-cli`:

```
update column family users
  with column_metadata = [{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}];
```

However the end result in CQL3 is not what I wanted:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  key text,
  column1 text,
  value blob,
  email text,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
  AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC);
```

What I expected is the same result as when I create the column family with the metadata from the beginning:

```
create column family users2 
  with key_validation_class = UTF8Type
  and comparator = UTF8Type
  and column_metadata = [{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}];
```

In that case the CQL3 view of this is what I want:

```
CREATE TABLE users2 (
  key text PRIMARY KEY,
  email text
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

Is there some way how I can add column metadata to a column family that was created without any - so that it would be viewed from CQL3 the same way as if the metadata was provided when the column family was created? Without re-creating the column family, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create **static** column using the **old** Thrift API. In fact, a static column is just a trick, e.g. a column with clustering value = NULL so there is only 1 instance of it for each partition key.

See those 2 slides for the explanation (sorry text in French):

http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-techniques-de-modlisation-avance/218

http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-techniques-de-modlisation-avance/219

You should take this opportunity to migrate to CQL. **Thrift** is deprecated and even disable by default starting with **Cassandra 3.x**

Comment: I'm not using *static columns* but column families that have the same columns in every row. The term *static column families* was defined in the [thrift to CQL3 migration guide](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3). And I'm migrating from Thrift to CQL - I just want to have nicer column names in CQL queries than `column1` and `value`.

Comment: See complete answer below

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see what you mean. Look at the **system** keyspace, table **schema_columnfamilies**.

I think the **label** of the partition keys and clustering columns are stored there.

It maybe possible to change them  but I don't know if it's a good idea to hack into those meta tables directly.

If you have **n** nodes, you'll probably need to update the label on all those nodes since the system keyspace has a **LocalStrategy**.

Execute this query to see the actual labels:

```
SELECT key_aliases,key_validator,column_aliases,comparator 
FROM system.schema_columnfamilies
WHERE keyspace_name='xxx'
AND columnfamily_name='users';
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (system schema tables). The only significant difference between the tables `users` and `users2` from my question is that `users` has `is_dense = True` in `schema_columnfamilies` and `users2` has `is_dense = False`. However it seems there is no easy way to do what I want apart from modifying the system tables - and I don't feel comfortable doing that.

Comment: @st_patriick, have you solved your problem? Tried to modify `system` table with no success.